# JSON Schema all possible combinations of enum

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm currently drafting up a JSON schema for some data. Let's say that my schema is of this form:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Title",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
                "property1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["ALPHA", "BETA"]
                 },
                "property2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["alpha", "beta"]
                },
                "val": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 100
                }
            },
        "required": ["property1", "property2", "val"]
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to specify that we want all possible combinations of the `property1` and `property2` values (in any order with no repeats)? The value of `val` will almost certainly not be unique.

All I can think of doing is adding `"minItems": 4, "maxItems": 4,` into the schema above the `"items"` object but this only means we will end up with exactly 4 items, and doesn't guarantee they will be unique.

I'm not asking for anyone to write the whole schema for me, just looking for pointers to documentation, or simple examples to push me in the right direction.

---

**Test cases** (*included to clarify my point*)

This should fail as one of the combinations is missing

```
{"data":[
     {
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "alpha",
     "val": 7
     },{
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 16
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 12
     }
]}
```

This should fail as one of the combinations is repeated

```
{"data":[
     {
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 73
     },{
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 72
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 73
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 71
     },{
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 68
     }
]}
```

This should pass

```
{"data":[
     {
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 26
     },{
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 26
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 32
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 83
     }
]}
```

This should also pass

```
{"data":[
     {
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 15
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 6
     },{
     "property1": "ALPHA",
     "property2": "alpha"
     "val": 65
     },{
     "property1": "BETA",
     "property2": "beta"
     "val": 37
     }
]}
```

Comment: Have you tried? This is not a code writing service

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I'm new to JSON Schemas so I've looked in all the places I could think to look and haven't found anything useful. This website is usually very good at pointing me in the right direction when I'm stuck, and as far as I could find, no one else had asked a question like this. All I can think of doing is restricting is so there must be exactly 4 items in the array, but this doesn't guarantee they are all unique

Answer (score 0):

Enum values can be objects, you can use it on the object level.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit please? I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can be done, but the solution would be so complex and unreadable that it wouldn't be worth doing.  I can't know for sure in your case, but usually situations like this indicate a poor choice in how you designed your data structure.  I would look into how you might restructure your data.